# How to use jq wildcard

Tags: json, select, key, jq, wildcard

I have the following json:

```json
{  
   "details":{  
      "car": "bmw",
      "addresses":{  
         "ext-118-21-8-0-29":[  
            {  
               "version":4,
               "addr":"89 Psr"
            },
            {  
               "version":6,
               "addr":"56 apT"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The key `ext-118-21-8-0-29` is dynamic it will change the next time and I don't know the exact value, that's why I need to use wildcard. I need to get the value of the key `addr` where version is `4`.

I'm expectig as output `89 Psr`

I tried the following using the function `startswith()`.

```bash
jq '.detail.addresses | select(startswith("ext"))'
```

But it end with an error.

> jq: error (at :0): startswith() requires string inputs

Comment: Just as a note, it seems in my exploration of a similar question that `requires string inputs` is referring to the pipeline of data in jq, rather than (as I at first interpreted it, and maybe you and/or others did or will too) the argument `"ext"`, which certainly seems like a string.  So, for example, in the snippet (from one of the answers, below) `.key|startswith("ext")`, `.key` is something that outputs a string, which is then the input to `startswith`, and that's what was complaining about (since you were giving it a more complicated data structure).  I hope this is helpful for someone.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you don't care about the keys in the object you're searching, you could just search the values of the object using `[]` which you could then filter to your desired results.

```
.details.addresses[][] | select(.version == 4).addr
```

If on the other hand you wanted to select keys that has a version 4, you could use `to_entries` to do this:

```
.details.addresses | to_entries[] | select(any(.value[]; .version == 4)).key
```

Comment: I have an issue, the code keep the double quote `"`, I have `"89 Psr"` as result string

Comment: Add the `-r` switch to get the raw output.

Answer (score 14):

If, as suggested by part of the question, you want to confine the search to key names starting with "ext":

```
.details.addresses
| to_entries[]
| select(.key|startswith("ext"))
| .value[]
| select(.version == 4)
| .addr
```

Towards the other end of the spectrum of permissiveness:

```
.details.addresses
| ..
| objects
| select(.version==4)
| .addr
```