# How to extract the operationId from an OpenAPI spec using JQ

Tags: jq, openapi

The OpenAPI spec defines operationId as child element of the method (GET, POST) of a path (e.g /customers ) which is a child of path. As dot notation it would look like:

```
.paths."/customers".get.operationId
.paths."/customers".post.operationId
.paths."/reports/daily".get.operationId
```

Or written with with wildcards: `.paths.*.*.operationId`

I looked at the following information:

- [How to use jq wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355822/how-to-use-jq-wildcard)
- https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/82
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320145/wildcard-in-jq-with-comparatives

and tried `.path | .. | .. | .operationId` but with no success.

My goal is to get a list of operationIds. What do I miss?

**Update** (as requested): [Sample Json OpenAPI spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v3.0/petstore.json)

**Update** To clarify from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663297): The `operationId` might occur in other positions, other than 3 levels below path. Don't need those

Comment: can you produce a sample JSON that resembles this structure?

Comment: The famous pet store example: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v3.0/petstore.json

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get array with all values for certain key in JSON wih JQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663297/get-array-with-all-values-for-certain-key-in-json-wih-jq)

Comment: The answer in the above question should work by changing the key to `operationId` i.e. `getpath(paths | select( .[-1] == "operationId" ) )`

Comment: Consider using an OpenAPI parser instead. Path definitions can be "imported" using `$ref`, and simple JSON parsing doesn't account for that. Or at least run your OpenAPI file through a `$ref` resolver before using `jq`.

Comment: My goal was for quick queries using JQ. The application itself uses an OpenAPI parser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My goal is to get a list of operationIds

Since you only want the `operationId` values under `.path`, you could write:

```
.path | .. | objects | select(has("operationId")) | .operationId
```

or if you want more control over the admissible paths, you could use the following as a template:

```
.path
| (paths | select(.[-1] == "operationId")) as $p
| getpath($p)
```

### "Wildcard" approach

`..` is a recursive operation that in effect follows all "paths" under a JSON entity; in this context, therefore, the wildcard "*" expression is more akin to jq's `.[]?` expression (i.e. postfix `[]?`).  So your meta-expression `.paths.*.*.operationId` could be written in jq as:

```
.paths[]?[]?.operationId
```

or

```
.paths[]?[]?.operationId?
```

depending on your interpretation of the expression with wildcards.

With the sample input, either of these produces:

```
"listPets"
"createPets"
"showPetById"
```

Comment: Works great on https://jqplay.org/s/ However I'm struggling to get it to run on zsh:

cat openapi.admin.json| jq '.paths[]?[]?.operationId'

it says: `jq: error (at <stdin>:1368): Cannot index string with string "operationId"`

Must be missing something

Comment: The jqplay link is incorrect. What is `.paths|type`?  Maybe you need a ? after .paths as in `.paths?[]?[]?.operationId`

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link, here you go: https://jqplay.org/s/ZDuC6nV7hu
As said: works on jqplay, zsh seems to want some other syntax?

Comment: The error message you report would arise if the input to .paths was a string, so check `.paths|type`, or use `debug`, e.g. `.paths|debug|type`

Comment: The solution was to add a `?` at the end, since some entries were missing, I'll update your reply, so future readers see the fully working one